# Estimating power from a voltage waveform

Tags: voltage, power, led

I'm working on a project in which I'm using a photodetector module. I'm transmitting a sine wave.

From the output of the photodetector ([C12702-12](https://www.hamamatsu.com/jp/en/product/type/C12702-12/index.html)) I can visualize the transmitted sine wave on the oscilloscope. Below, an image with some of these waves, just for reference.

[image]

However, in order to achieve what I'm aiming to calculate, I need the power value.

So, my question is if there's a way that I can obtain the power (in watts) from this voltage data (e.g., using the peak values).

Maybe could I somehow estimate the current or the resistance?

If that's not feasible, how could I measure the current (or resistance?) in the lab?

Thanks!

Comment: You need photodetector specs if you want the power of the illuminating source.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I want the received power. These sine waves are received signals

Comment: The optical power, right? Then you need the photodetector specs on how much output it produces based on the illumination.

Comment: Not exactly the optical power (the power that hits the photodetector area); this would be even more difficult to obtain, I think. 

My signal demodulation (when I eventually use a modulated signal) would be based on this electrical signal, which is the optical power, converted to a photocurrent and amplified at the module, which then outputs it for the user.

Comment: Power of what? Resistance of what? Is there more to the circuit? The power going into the oscilloscope is (by design) approximately zero. The power delivered by the photodetector to a load depends on the load. The power illuminating the photodetector isn't directly knowable unless you have a reference to work from.

Comment: I'm thinking of the electrical power of this sine wave because I want to calculate the SNR eventually. There's nothing more to the circuit, I just connect the output of the PD module to the scope. So, I thought of a resistance (or current) in order to obtain the electrical power. Maybe actually my reasoning doesn't make sense?

Comment: Your reasoning is not wrong but is roundabout. If all you want is SNR, remember that SNR is a ratio. So you can use any arbitrary resistance since they cancel out, therefore I recommend you just use 1. But if you use 1 you are pretty much only working with ratios of V^2.  Or just use linear amplitude ratios and when you convert to dB, it automatically converts to power. since dB is always in terms of power. That's why the dB formula that uses linear amplitudes ratios has 20 instead of 10. That 2 is there for the amplitude squared part to convert it to power when it is put into dB form.

Answer (score 0):

For IR input 0.5 [A/W], is a common sensitivity for silicon photodiodes as well. This refers to output current for input Power at the wavelength in datasheet.

RMS = 0.707* peak for sine wave
0.5A/W = 2W/A or **2mW (in) per mA (out)**

Answer (score 0):

The photodector module you are using consists of an avalanche photodiode, a transimpedance amplifier and some biasing circuitry. So the optical power that is received is converted to a current by the photodiode. This current is then converted to a voltage by the transimpedance amplifier. You can measure this voltage using the BNC connector.

So the meaningful power quantity represented by the measured voltage is the received optical power. The datasheet of the module provides the necessary information for calculating it:

[image: Amplifier data from datasheet]

Since you are using the C12702-12 we need to look at the last row. You can calculate the optical power by dividing the measured voltage by the photoelectric sensitivity. You can also use the noise equivalent power for SNR calculations.

Maybe also have a look at the provided [technical note](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/apd_modules_kacc9010e.pdf) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you! I have not thought in this "reverse" manner. A problem is that I do not know the exact gain values (it is configurable, but I don't have a reference to know how much it is) but I think I can make a good estimation anyway.

Comment: You mean the photodetector is configurable? The only thing I see about this is the note of the factory gain setting of M=30 which is the multiplier of the avlanche diode. The datasheet doesn't show any interface for configuration, how do you configure it?

Comment: Yes, there is a trimmer to adjust the gain. This manual describes it, page 8: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11b5KVPhEim-2j0K-m512YBX__imL63Uu/view?usp=sharing (I couldn't find it on the internet, I guess I got it when we bought the device)

Comment: Well at least there is a plot of the gain vs trimmer rotation count, so hopefully you can figure out the gain with the current settings.

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine. Anyway, I've managed to obtain the SNR, and now it's just a matter of fine tuning the results and plotting charts. Thank you very much again!